# "corrupted double-linked list" in Openpose

Tags: python, openpose

I've recently gotten the following error from my python code:

```
corrupted double-linked list
```

I call this function in `openpose`:

```
    def forward(self, image, display = False):
    """
    Forward: Takes in an image and returns the human 2D poses, along with drawn image if required

    Parameters
    ----------
    image : color image of type ndarray
    display : If set to true, we return both the pose and an annotated image for visualization

    Returns
    -------
    array: ndarray of human 2D poses [People * BodyPart * XYConfidence]
    displayImage : image for visualization
    """
    shape = image.shape
    displayImage = np.zeros(shape=(image.shape),dtype=np.uint8)
    size = np.zeros(shape=(3),dtype=np.int32)
    self._libop.forward(self.op, image, shape[0], shape[1], size, displayImage, display)
    array = np.zeros(shape=(size),dtype=np.float32)
    self._libop.getOutputs(self.op, array)
    if display:
        return array, displayImage
    return array
```

and I get the output in this way:

```
    key_points, img = pose.forward(frame, display=True)
```

How can I get this output?